# Can't Delete Webmatrix Site

Tags: webmatrix

From the "My Sites" view, one-by-one I selected several web sites I wanted to delete.  For each I was given the option of "delete site" or "delete site and content".  I chose "delete site and content."

However, when afterward I chose to re-create one of those deleted sits Webmatrix says "A site named 'MySite' already exists - You will need to enter a different site name."

What do I need to do to make WebMatrix REALLY delete a site?  Why didn't it completely delete the sites I requested in the first place?

Comment: Why do people close these types of questions?  From the FAQ it says questions about software tools commonly used by programmers and practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession are questions that can be asked.

Comment: Absolutely not off topic. Good question with a good answer below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably need to delete the site's entry in your applicationhost.config file. This can usually be found in Documents > IISExpress > config.

Comment: This really is the easiest way to solve this issue. ESPECIALLY if WebMatrix decides to error while trying to create the site... Also, XML (like the applicationhost.config file appears to be) has such high readability it is as easy as `CTRL+F` to find the site you are looking to delete.

Comment: Perfect answer yet again by Mike. Thanks

Comment: I am surprise there is not better consistency checks in this product for dirty data, especially during site deletion. Yuk!.